# Promises in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, promise, angular-promise

I'm using Angular with CoffeeScript. 
I have 3 functions `getSomeData1(), getSomeData2(), getSomeData3()` that I need to execute sequentially. I have the following and it works fine.

```
    getSomeData1: ->
        @http.get("someRestUrl1")
           .success((data) =>
              getSomeData2()

    getSomeData2: ->
        @http.get("someRestUrl2")
           .success((data) =>
              getSomeData3()

    getSomeData3: ->
        @http.get("someRestUrl3")
```

I would like to make it more readable placing all the functions in one place. Something like,

```
getSomeData1()
.then(getSomeData2())
.then(getSomeData3())
```

This will help in understanding the sequence of operations easily.

Any suggestions to achieve this? Do I need to use $q ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions to achieve this?

Just omit those `success` calls and directly return the `$http` promises from each of those functions. And don't forget to pass *callback*s to `.then()`, not function calls.

```
getSomeData1: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl1")
getSomeData2: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl2")
getSomeData3: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl3")

getSomeData1().then(getSomeData2).then(getSomeData3)
```

> Do I need to use `$q`?

No, because `$http` already does for you. You just can consume the promises.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to pass on the data retrieved from the first call to the second?

Comment: Yes, `getSomeData2` does receive it as its argument. Just give the callback function a parameter :-)